# Pagination Laravel with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

everyone
I've somes problems when try paginate some results of my eloquent consult with AJAX, everything works, even the paginate, I've 5 recordsin DB, and I show then in a view, and paginate with the links method, the problem is, when I select the second item of the paginator, change the records well, but repeat the layout, so, a users are in the page, and select the second item in the paginator, change the records in the view without refresh the page, but, at the same time, load again the layout with the navbar, footer, and all that thnigs; here's my code:

```
public function show_events(Request $request)
    {
        $events = Event::all();

        $ultimos = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(3);
        if ($request->ajax) {
            return view('events.partials.last', compact('ultimos'));
        }

        return View('events.index', compact('events', 'ultimos')); -> This view has the layout and anothers things
    }
```

In that view, I've a div with ID and include the piece of code where are all the records with the foreach, and this is the div:

```
<div id="item-events" style="position: relative;">
          <h2 style="text-align: center; color: #009de2; margin-bottom: 5px;">Últimos eventos agregados</h2>
          @include('events.partials.last')
        </div>
```

And here's my AJAX:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
      if (window.location.hash) {
          var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
          if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
              return false;
          }else{
              getEvent(page);
          }
      }
  });

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $(document).on('click', '.pagination a',function(event)
      {
          $('li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
          event.preventDefault();

          var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
          var page=$(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];

          getEvent(page);
      });
  });

  function getEvent(page) {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '?page=' + page,
            type: "get",
            datatype: "html",
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {
            $("#item-events").empty().html(data);
            location.hash = page;
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
              alert('Lo sentimos, ocurrió un error.');
        });
  }
```

Someone knows what happened?
Thanks for try help me, I'll realy gratefull!

Comment: did you got an error ?

Comment: Yes, this one, appear in the console, after change the records:
app.js:29 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: i assume this is a comment return View('events.index', compact('events', 'ultimos')); -> This view has the layout and anothers thing. i mean after ->

Comment: Yes, it's just a comment

Comment: can you try to add async: true on your ajax option